# jQuery - Why can't I add the .php suffix to this Ajax load function

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#bootChooserControl')
      .load('/jqia2/action/fetchBootStyleOptions');

    $('#bootChooserControl').change(function(event){
      $('#productDetailPane').load(
        '/jqia2/action/fetchProductDetails',
        {style: $(event.target).val()},
        function() { $('[value=""]',event.target).remove(); }
      );
    });

  });
</script>
```

My question is that why it doesn't work for me if I change `load('/jqia2/action/fetchBootStyleOptions')` to `load('/jqia2/action/fetchBootStyleOptions.php')`

The same problem happens for `fetchProductDetails`.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you visit those pages with your browser?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in Firebug? http://getfirebug.com

Comment: yes, I can directly access those pages.

However, I found sth new. Please see my comments on Robert.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/jqia2/action/fetchBootStyleOptions
```

is being rewritten by the .htacccess rule to

```
/jqia2/chapter8/bootcloset/actions/fetchBootStyleOptions.php
```

so if you would like to call it directly, you could use

```
load('/jqia2/chapter8/bootcloset/actions/fetchBootStyleOptions.php')
```

Answer (score 1):

Barring the fact that you're just pointing to invalid files by adding the .php (try navigating manually by putting '`window.location = "/jqia2/action/fetchBootStyleOptions.php";` in your function and see if it pulls up) you may be having an issue with MultiViews, check your .htaccess and you can also check out http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/content-negotiation.html

Comment: Hello all,

I have found the content of this file .htaccess
////////////////////////////////
RewriteEngine on

# /action/xxx -> /chapter8/bootcloset/actions/xxx.php
RewriteRule ^action/(.*) /jqia2/chapter8/bootcloset/actions/$1.php [L]
///////////////////////////////////////////////

Does this cause the problem?
thank you

Comment: By removing all statements inside .htaccess doesn't solve this issue.

thank you

Comment: Have you tried the other part, having your script redirect you to that path.

Comment: Hello Robert,

This is aJax call. I don't know how I can use 
window.location = "/jqia2/action/fetchBootStyleOptions.php
and put it inside load function.

best wishes